# The fast way to count distinct by field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, optimization, aggregation-framework

I want a faster way to count the distinct by field in MongoDB Collection that contain more than 10 Million documents. My schema looks like this :

```json
[
  {
    //-- type and date
    "date": "2023-11-09",
    "type": "my_type",
    "resource": "2222"
  },
  {
    //-- type and date
    "date": "2023-11-09",
    "type": "my_type",
    "resource": "1111"
  },
  {
    //-- type and date
    "date": "2023-11-09",
    "type": "my_type",
    "resource": "1111"
  }
]
```

I want a very performance query that can count the distinct resources over my collection

**the actual aggregation I use**

```json
[
  {
    $sort:
      {
        resource: 1,
      },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      distinctResources: {
        $addToSet: "$resource",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $size: ["$resource"],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

**The output I need**

```json
{
  "_id": null,
  "totalDistinct": 2 // in this case 1111 and 2222
}
```

Note:

- this can't be pre calculated !
- I can add an index on resource

Comment: Can you add a sample output (and maybe also the aggregation that you are using now)? Do you want a list of all distinct values in field `resource` or only the count? Why can't it be pre-calculated?

Comment: can't be pre-calculated because I have very big number of possibilities to filter the documents on which I want to count distinct `resource`

Comment: Your source data has field `resource` whereas the aggregation pipeline uses `resourcesInspected`. Are you doing something else in your aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's just by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
[
  { $sort: { resource: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$resource" } },
  { $count: "totalDistinct" }
]
```

Do you have an index on `resource`? If not, then the `$sort` is pointless.

Anyway, you may try also without `$sort`

Comment: Yes I tried it , and i have an index on resource. but it takes to 10 seconds which is not acceptable